# Hide ECB menu in a single web part

Tags: web-part, ecb-menu

I have a web part that displays frequently asked questions on a landing page for a SharePoint site.

[image: FAQ web part]

I've already managed to hide column headers in the web part to make it a little neater by using:

```
<style> 
#WebPartWPQ2 tr.ms-viewheadertr 
{ 
display: none;
} 
</style>
```

Is there a similar way to hide this menu drop down:

[image: ECB menu]

I hid the column headers by identifying the web part name and the element name, but I can't seem to find the right element name for the drop down menu.

I want to hide it in just this one web part as well, and not the whole page or the whole site. If anyone can suggest the element name for this that could help.

Comment: If it's a standard list you should just be able to modify the webpart and then under the web part setting set "Toolbar Type " to "No Toolbar".

Comment: My opinion is instead selecting "no toolbar: option. i think creating a .js file is more useful as this can be used anywhere in future too for any small modifications as in sharepoint there are many limitations.

Comment: @user19952 I currently have "No Toolbar" turned off but it's still there

Comment: Change the Chrome Type to "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Edit page. Then select the webpart and click on Edit Web Part. Then click on edit the view. You will notice that "Title (linked to item with edit menu) " is selected. Uncheck it. And select "Title (linked to item)" column. This way you won't get ECB menu

Answer (score 0):

The down arrow is basically an image and you can locate the name of that using F12 developer tools and then in the DOM explorer selecting the select element icon and move it on the down arrow of your FAQ webpart. The DOM explorer will take take you to the exact position of this element and show you the name of it For e.g it would be something like "ms-WPHeaderMenuImg" and then you can see the css properties of it on the right side of the DOM Explorer. you just have to add display :none property to it. the image will be hidden and you will no longer be able to see it.

You can do this by incorporating a .js file in the content editor webpart and making the content editor webpart hidden.

This will be only applied to the webpart that you wanted and not for all the webparts on the page

Njoy. If any questions please let me know